# How to show custom 500 error page in production only in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, exception, error-handling, symfony-4.4

I created a custom 500 error page by overriding the default 500 page. I did this by creating `exception.html.twig` template in `templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/exception.html.twig`. But the problem is that it shows this template in all environments when a 500 error occurs.

How can I tell the application to show `exception.html.twig` template only in production? In dev and local I want to display the exceptions to the user as we have in normal applications.

Comment: One way would be to only set a [custom handler in your production config](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-error-output-for-non-html-formats).

Comment: Heee... that should never appear on dev per default? Are you sure your dev env are really set as dev? And are you also sure you composer install as dev?

Comment: See: _In the development environment, Symfony catches all the exceptions and displays a special exception page with lots of debug information to help you discover the root problem:_ and _Since these pages contain a lot of sensitive internal information, Symfony won't display them in the production environment. Instead, it'll show a simple and generic error page:_ in the page @ChrisHaas linked above

Comment: Oh but, as per the doc, you should have created an `error.html.twig` for that, and not overriding the `exception.html.twig` file

Comment: Thanks @β.εηοιτ.βε it's working now.